# ng-bootstrap accordion applies style to child icons

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

[image: Star shows when there is no focus on the accordian]

Star shows when there is no focus on the accordion

[image]

Star dissappears when there's focus on the accordian

Here's my CSS to display the star to the left of the accordion:

```
.icon-star2.relevant-source {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -5em;
}
```

Here's the markup[replaced variables with x to hide sensitive info]:

```
 <ngb-accordion class="accordion accordion-alternate">
           <ngb-panel class="source-accordion" *ngFor="x">
                            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                                <i *ngIf="x > 0" class="icon-star2 relevant-source"
                                   title="This source contains {{x}} of the top 10 most relevant documents.">
                                </i>
                                <span class="source-link source-link-text">{{x}}</span><span class="float-right source-link">
                                {{x | number:0 }}</span>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                                List of documents
                            </ng-template>
                        </ngb-panel>
                    </ngb-accordion>
```

My goal is to have a star next to certain accordion elements with a title on it. (native tooltip)

I've tried a handfull of things but I can't seem to get this issue resolved. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try with deep

```
/deep/ ngb-accordion > ngb-panel> i.icon-star2.relevant-source{
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: -5em;
}
```